# Flutter - Build failed after updating to v1.17

Tags: flutter, dart

I updated flutter to v1.17 stable release. Also updated dependencies to latest version. Build failed with this error :

```
Compiler message:
    ../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/extended_image-0.7.2/lib/src/gesture/extended_image_slide_page_route.dart:333:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'animation'.
            animation: animation,
            ^^^^^^^^^
    ../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/route.dart:435:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition({
```

How do I resolve this?

EDIT:

After running pub cache repair I am getting a new error

```
 error: /Users/yahya/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.13/ios/Classes/UserAgent.h: No such file or directory (in target 'firebase_messaging' from project 'Pods')
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning cache and restarting? (invalidate caches) The first error has a path that goes through .pub-cache.

Comment: I ran flutter clean and clean build folder from Xcode. It didn't work.